# Inactive customers mysql query optimization

Tags: mysql

I have a customer table with million of records.
Customer

```
id | name | .....
```

I also have an orders table with

```
id | custID | orderDate | ....
```

I need to find all the people who have not placed an order for more than 30 days.It should also include people who have never placed the order

```
select name,customer.id from customer where id in 

(select custID from orders where datediff(curdate(),orders.orderDate) > 30 )

union

select name,customer.id from customer  left join orders on customer.id = orders.custID where orders.id is null
```

How can i optimize the query ?

Comment: The original query doesn't seem correct, it will return all customers with orders older than 30 days even if they have more recent orders. Also post an the result of `EXPLAIN` if you can.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
select name,t.id 
  from customer t where 
    not exists (
        select 1 
          from orders where 
          custID=t.id
          and
          datediff(curdate(),orders.orderDate) <= 30 )
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this one

```
Select Customer.Custid,
Customer.name
from Customer
left join orders on 
customer.custid = orders.custid and
datediff(getdate(),orders.orderdate)>30)

where 
orders.id is null
```